How to execute a SQL query in SQL Server without headers in the output?
I am working with SQL Server and need to execute a query that retrieves data from a table but without the column headers in the output. Here's the specific query I am using:
SELECT * FROM CustomerSampleReceiptCheck;

When I run the following SQL query in SSMS, the output displays both the column headers and the data. For example:



Column1
Column2




Value1
Data1


Value2
Data2



I would like the output to look like this:
Value1 Data1 
Value2 Data2 

Desired result:
I am looking for a way to retrieve the data without any column headers directly in SSMS or through command-line utilities. Specifically, I want a method that allows me to execute my query and obtain the results in a clean format, without any additional headers.

The query just returns the data (two rows). It is the tool that shows you the column names in the title. If you write an app yourself, you can decide to display the data without any titles.

How you display the data is up to you; that's logic you write in your application. I am sure whatever ever language you are using to consume the data has the ability to omit the headers. For example, if you were using PowerShell, Export-Csv, for example, has a NoHeader switch.

There are no headers in query results. It's up to the client application to decide how to display them. SSMS is a client application like any other. It's a DBA tool though and like all DBA tools it displays column names because that's what DBAs want.

What is the actual problem anyway? What does "clean format" mean? No DBA would call a file without headers "clean", because we'd have to guess which column is which (assuming there are columns). We'd use various expletives, because now we'd have to depend on column order, which can easily change. Like the one I found last Tuesday, with the Currency and Type reversed

A CSV with columns is better than one without. If those columns can contain commas or newlines, they can be quoted. Or one can use rare characters like § as separators. If the columns vary then a) they can't be the result of a SQL export and b) there are formats that support that, like Parquet, ORC and more, or even XML or JSON

The closest you are likely going to come in SSMS is to set the column headers to blanks using ... AS [ ]. Fiddle. However, as others have pointed out, if you want a specific presentation for the end-user, you should write your own custom presentation layer.
